# How to correctly deserialize a Json string

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net, json-deserialization

I have an issue when Parsing a Json string to a C# JObject. The end result is not consistent with the starting string.

```cs
var original = "{\"System.String\":[\"AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAGAQAAAA53d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQs=\", \"mscorlib\"],\"System.Boolean\":[\"AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAEAQAAAA5TeXN0ZW0uQm9vbGVhbgEAAAAHbV92YWx1ZQABAAs=\", \"mscorlib\"],\"System.Boolean\":[\"AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAEAQAAAA5TeXN0ZW0uQm9vbGVhbgEAAAAHbV92YWx1ZQABAAs=\", \"mscorlib\"]}";
var parsed = JObject.Parse(original);
```

This works but my parsed object actually looks like this:

```
{{
  "System.String": [
    "AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAGAQAAAA53d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQs=",
    "mscorlib"
  ],
  "System.Boolean": [
    "AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAEAQAAAA5TeXN0ZW0uQm9vbGVhbgEAAAAHbV92YWx1ZQABAAs=",
    "mscorlib"
  ]
}}
```

As you can see it removed one of the objects, why?

I have also tried by using the proper converter

```cs
var parsed2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(original);
```

Can I get around this by overloading the settings?

Comment: Your json is invalid. You cannot have two properties with the same name (System.Boolean). Use an array instead of an object to hold your values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Cannot contain 2 items with the same key.

`System.Boolean` is present twice in your JSON.

To provide an example on why this is a problem, just think about what you would expect `parsed["System.Boolean"]` to return?

If the JSON you are parsing is created by your system, you can modify it so it contains an array of objects instead of key/value pairs directly in it.

Example:

```
{ 
  "items" : [
      {
      "System.String": [
        "AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAGAQAAAA53d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQs=",
        "mscorlib"]
      },
      {
        "System.Boolean": [
        "AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAEAQAAAA5TeXN0ZW0uQm9vbGVhbgEAAAAHbV92YWx1ZQABAAs=",
        "mscorlib"]
      }
    ]
}
```